# jscroll plugin is not working, with multiple scroll

Tags: jquery, infinite-scroll

I am using jscroll plugin in my website front page. i use this and it work fine. But when i add more then one scroll on same page, it working only on one scroll.

website for jscroll : http://jscroll.com

html code:

for first column

```
<div class="containerHome scrollNew">

    <!-- BEGIN: a1_loop -->

    <div class="single {CLASS_HERE} ">
        //Html Content Here
        <a href="/blub_site/admin/ajax/newStart/?article=2" class="newArticlesATag">#</a> 
    </div>

    <!-- END: a1_loop -->

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.scrollNew').jscroll({ 
            nextSelector: 'a:last'
    });
    </script>
</div>
```

For second col:

```
<div class="containerHome scrollMid">
    <!-- BEGIN: a2_loop --> 
        //html code
        <a href="/blub_site/admin/ajax/newStart/?article={SLUG}" class="midArticlesATag">#</a>
    </div>
    <!-- END: a2_loop -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('.scrollMid').jscroll({ 
            nextSelector: 'a:last'
        });
    </script>
</div>
```